# Make cmd-click on a file name in iTerm add that filename to the command

Tags: command-line, terminal, git, iterm2, iterm

By default, iTerm lets you cmd-click filenames and urls to open them with the system's default app. I want to be able to change that so it adds the filename to the command I'm currently typing.

This would be useful for my git flow: `git status` → `git add ...` (at this point I want to just click on the relevant files one after the other and have them appended).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've figured this out:
[image: iterm preferences]

Go to `Preferences` → `Profiles` → `Advanced` and under Semantic History choose `Run coprocess...`, then in the text box type `printf '\1 '` (note that I've added a space so that you can click multiple files consecutively).

Comment: This is quite helpful - thank you. I wish/wonder if it were possible to retain both behaviours with a differing key sequence.